# How to pass slug in generic view (Django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

How can i pass a slug in this generic 'ListView', I was confused by the get_context_data function. The slug is in the 'Profile' model.

views.py

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'feed/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            liked = [i for i in Post.objects.all() if Like.objects.filter(user = self.request.user, post=i)]
            context['liked_post'] = liked
        return context
```

Comment: What error do you get or what are you trying to do?

Comment: I haven't got any error yet as I'm not sure how to apply the slug in the first place.

Comment: How is Profile model linked to the Post model?

Answer (score 0):

You need no additional code for the Generic CBV to fetch your model's instance with the slug.

You just need to create the appropriate url with the <slug:slug> parameter.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

As Indox recommended , i didn't need to add any additional code to the view , I used slug:slug on the url pattern , plus in  my templates where there was a {% url 'home' user.profile.slug %}  , I was missing the user.profile.slug at the end, after adding that it worked fine.